# How Jump to with collections of data in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, collections

I'm implementing the `Jump to...` functionality in my project. What I want is:

1. If the user is in the **first item** the left button is **NOT** included.
2. If the user is in the **last item** the right button is **NOT** included.
3. The left button should have a link same with the link before the current/selected item.
4. The right button should have a link same with the link after the current/selected item.

Please see my code below:

*Controller*

```
$course = Course::with([
  'assignments' => $undeleted,
  'quizzes' => $undeleted,
  'add_links' => $undeleted
])->findOrFail($id);
$course_items = collect($course->assignments);
$course_items = $course_items->merge(collect($course->quizzes));
$course_items = $course_items->merge(collect($course->add_links));
$course_items = $course_items->sortBy('item_number');
```

*View*

```
<div class="jump-to">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">

            @foreach($course->topics as $topic)
                @foreach(collect($topic->assignments)->merge(collect($topic->quizzes))->merge(collect($topic->add_links))->sortBy('item_number') as $first_item)
                    @if($first_item->id != $assignment->id)
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                        </a>
                    @endif
                    <?php break 2; ?>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Jump to <div class="caret"></div>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    @foreach($course->topics as $topic)
                        <li class="jdivider">
                            Topic {{ $topic->topic_number }}
                        </li>
                        @foreach(collect($topic->assignments)->merge(collect($topic->quizzes))->merge(collect($topic->add_links))->sortBy('item_number') as $topic_item)
                            <li>
                                @if($topic_item->item_type() == 'assignment')
                                    <a title="Assignment: {{ $topic_item->name }}" class="regular-link" href="{{ route('assignment.view', ['course_id' => $course->id, 'id' => $topic_item->id]) }}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> {{ str_limit($topic_item->name, 15) }}
                                    </a>
                                @elseif($topic_item->item_type() == 'quiz')
                                    <a title="Quiz: {{ $topic_item->name }}" class="regular-link" href="{{ route('quiz.view', ['course_id' => $course->id, 'id' => $topic_item->id]) }}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> {{ str_limit($topic_item->name, 15) }}
                                    </a>
                                @elseif($topic_item->item_type() == 'add_link')
                                    <a href="#">
                                        @if(!empty($topic_item->file_location) && in_array(strtolower(last(explode('.', $topic_item->file_location))), ['pdf', 'docx', 'doc']))
                                            <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
                                        @elseif(empty($topic_item->file_location))
                                            <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                                        @else
                                            <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                                        @endif
                                        {{ str_limit($topic_item->name, 15) }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example**
`dropdown links`:

*Assignment1*
*Assignment2*
*Quiz1*
*QUiz2*
*Reviewer1*

If I clicked *Assignment2*, the left button, has the `id` or `link` to `Assignment1`. If I clicked *Reviewer1*, the right button disappears and the left button has the `id` or link to *Quiz2* and same with the other links.